# how to derive filter condition from table rows

Tags: sql, teradata

How do i derive the filter condition in bteq based on rows like given below?

TABLE B:

```
COLA COLB COLC
1    CODE  AAA
1    DESC  BBB
1    TYPE  CCC
```

Here is some code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE CODE IN ('AAA') AND DESC IN ('BBB') AND TYPE IN ('CCC')
```

Comment: Add some more sample data and also specify the expected result.

Comment: How many tables actually exist here?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to compare the value of `COLB` and `COLC` within a row.  If that's the case, then you could possibly use a `LIKE` operator or an array comparison.  What is the data type of `COLC`?  What is your definition of `IN` in your pseudo-query?

Comment: This seems to be a request to use Table B to generate dynamic SQL with varying number of predicates referencing arbitrary column names and potentially lists of column values. While it may be possible to do that in BTEQ, you are probably better off using some procedural  language (stored procedure in the database, Python script on the client, etc.) to build the query.

Answer (score 2):

One approach here would be to aggregate by `COLA`, and then add three assertions for the key/values you expect:

```
SELECT
    COLA
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    COLA
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COLB = 'CODE' AND COLC = 'AAA' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COLB = 'DESC' AND COLC = 'BBB' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COLB = 'TYPE' AND COLC = 'CCC' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: `COLB` and `COLC` is in the `B` table, and OP want to filter table `A`. You're only querying one table, so how is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write query using common table expression.

```sql
WITH CTE_TableB(ColA, Code, DESC,TYPE) AS
(
SELECT COLA, CASE WHEN COLB = 'Code' THEN COLC ELSE NULL AS Code
           , CASE WHEN COLB = 'DESC' THEN COLC ELSE NULL AS DESC
           , CASE WHEN COLB = 'TYPE' THEN COLC ELSE NULL AS TYPE
FROM TABLEB
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_TableB
WHERE  CODE IN ('AAA') AND DESC IN ('BBB') AND TYPE IN ('CCC');
```

Or using derived table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT COLA, CASE WHEN COLB = 'Code' THEN COLC ELSE NULL AS Code
           , CASE WHEN COLB = 'DESC' THEN COLC ELSE NULL AS DESC
           , CASE WHEN COLB = 'TYPE' THEN COLC ELSE NULL AS TYPE
FROM TABLEB
) AS t
WHERE  CODE IN ('AAA') AND DESC IN ('BBB') AND TYPE IN ('CCC');
```

Comment: `COLB` and `COLC` is in the `B` table, and OP want to filter table `A`. You're not doing anything with table `A`, so how is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

To filter table `A` using the values in table `B`, and assuming that a column without values in table `B` means unfiltered on that column, you can do it like this:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM A
 WHERE ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.COLB = 'CODE' )
      OR A.CODE IN ( SELECT B.COLC FROM B WHERE B.COLB = 'CODE' ) )
   AND ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.COLB = 'DESC' )
      OR A.DESC IN ( SELECT B.COLC FROM B WHERE B.COLB = 'DESC' ) )
   AND ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.COLB = 'TYPE' )
      OR A.TYPE IN ( SELECT B.COLC FROM B WHERE B.COLB = 'TYPE' ) )
```

Comment: I see no relationship between the "A" and "B" tables whatsoever, and would assume it is just a typo, and that there is only one table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The relationship is that `B.COLB` contains the *name* of a column in table `A`, and `B.COLC` contains the value to match in that table `A` column. By *guess* is that the integer value of `B.COLA` represents the `A` table. It's the only way the question makes any sense to me, but it does make lots of sense that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` or `exists` for this purpose:

```
select a.*
from a 
where a.code in (select b.colc from b where b.colb = 'CODE') and
      a.desc in (select b.colc from b where b.colb = 'DESC') and
      a.type in (select b.colc from b where b.colb = 'TYPE');
```

The one caveat is that this assumes that there is at least one of each value in table `b`.

You can handle missing values.  One method uses additional subqueries:

```
select a.*
from a 
where (a.code in (select b.colc from b where b.colb = 'CODE') or
       not exists (select 1 from b where b.colb = 'CODE')
      ) and
      (a.desc in (select b.colc from b where b.colb = 'DESC') or
       not exists (select 1 from b where b.colb = 'DESC')
      ) and
      (a.type in (select b.colc from b where b.colb = 'TYPE') or
       not exists (select 1 from b where b.colb = 'TYPE')
      );
```